# Can't update user's info clicking on a submit

Tags: php, mysql

Everytime an user register in my website, they have a "free account".
In my website there're 4 types of accounts:

Free - 2GB

Basic - 5GB

Ultra - 10GB

Plus - 25GB

Each one with an unique id.
I have created this code. Depending of the submit you click, your user get one of those accounts (Basic Ultra or Plus).

```
    public static function ComprobarTarifa($user){
        $sql = "SELECT id_tipocuenta FROM canal WHERE id = '$user'";
        $resultado = self::Conexion($sql);
        $verificacion = false;

        if(isset($resultado)) {
            $fila = $resultado->fetch();
            if($fila !== false){
                $verificacion=true;
            }
        }
        return $verificacion;
    }

    public static function AmpliarCuenta($user, $tarifa){
        $sql = "UPDATE canal SET id_tipocuenta = '$tarifa' WHERE id = '$user'";
        $resultado = self::Conexion($sql);
        return $resultado;
    }

    public static function AmpliarCuentaErrores(){
        $error = "";
        $tarifa = 0;

        if(isset($_POST["tarifaBasic"])){
            $tarifa = 2;

            if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){
                if(self::ComprobarTarifa($_SESSION["usuario"]) != $tarifa){
                    DataBase::AmpliarCuenta($_SESSION["usuario"], $tarifa);
                    $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>Ya estás usando esa tarifa...</div></div></div>";
                }
            } else {
                $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>Debes iniciar sesión primero...</div></div></div>";
            }
        }

        if(isset($_POST["tarifaUltra"])){
            $tarifa = 3;

            if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){
                if(self::ComprobarTarifa($_SESSION["usuario"]) != $tarifa){
                    DataBase::AmpliarCuenta($_SESSION["usuario"], $tarifa);
                    $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>Ya estás usando esa tarifa...</div></div></div>";
                }
            } else {
                $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>Debes iniciar sesión primero...</div></div></div>";
            }
        }

        if(isset($_POST["tarifaPlus"])){
            $tarifa = 4;

            if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){
                if(self::ComprobarTarifa($_SESSION["usuario"]) != $tarifa){
                    DataBase::AmpliarCuenta($_SESSION["usuario"], $tarifa);
                    $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>Ya estás usando esa tarifa...</div></div></div>";
                }
            } else {
                $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>Debes iniciar sesión primero...</div></div></div>";
            }
        }
        return $error;
    }
```

The problem is that my database doesnt update... What could it be?
Error divs dont appear...

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: They dont even appear

Comment: Where *specifically* does it fail?  "The database doesn't update" isn't really a description of the problem.  Is the `UPDATE` command executed at all?  What are the values when it is?  Also note that those look a lot like SQL injection vulnerabilities, which should probably be corrected otherwise not updating the database will be the least of your worries with your users.

Comment: @David For example, I click on the button of PLUS ACCOUNT, and I have the free one. Then, my account type id should be 4, not 1. And a div should appear saying: Your account has been updated. But, nothing happens

Comment: Error logs don't *"appear"*, they are maintained on your server.

Comment: `return $error;` isn't a *real* error.

Comment: @Antonio: We can't debug this on your computer *for you*.  Your code isn't a black box, you *can* in fact perform some basic debugging to narrow down the problem.  I understand that when you click the button what you expect to happen doesn't happen.  But of the *many* steps between clicking the button and seeing output, you need to find out *where* the system is failing.

Comment: What do you mean? What should I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing the error message even if everything is OK. You forgot the else at all the instances here:

```
if(self::ComprobarTarifa($_SESSION["usuario"]) != $tarifa){
    DataBase::AmpliarCuenta($_SESSION["usuario"], $tarifa);
    $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>Ya estás usando esa tarifa...</div></div></div>";
}
```

That should actually be:

```
if(self::ComprobarTarifa($_SESSION["usuario"]) != $tarifa){
    DataBase::AmpliarCuenta($_SESSION["usuario"], $tarifa);
} else {
    $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>Ya estás usando esa tarifa...</div></div></div>";
}
```